# Write a CSV file

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I have a class that I've written in C# and decorated with FileHelpers attributes

```
[DelimitedRecord(","), IgnoreFirst(1)]
class UserAndValues
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserFavourites> Favourites {get;set;}

    public UserAndValues()
    { }
}

class UserFavourites
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

I then call the CSV writer

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<UserAndValues>();
engine.WriteFile(myPath, myListOfUsers);
```

I get the following error:

> The field: 'k__BackingField' has the type: ICollection`1
>   that is not a system type, so this field need a CustomConverter (
>   Please Check the docs for more Info).

I would like to write out a file that basically looks like

```
UserId, FirstName, LastName, Favourite1Id, Favourite1Title, Favourite2Id, Favourite2Title...  
1, Joe, Smith, 1, Random Title, 2, More Title, ...
```

The favourites collection could be 10-50 records deep and changes based on the file.

I will not need to read this file, just write it.

How can I generate a CSV using the above class? (I can modify the class structure)

Comment: The help pages list a Converter example for  [FieldConverter], did you try that?

Comment: I did look, but I didn't see any examples similar to my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, very untested:

```
class UserAndValues
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [FieldConverter(typeof(MyListConverter))] 
    public ICollection<UserFavourites> Favourites {get;set;}
}

public class MyListConverter: ConverterBase 
{ 

    public override object StringToField(string from) 
    { 
      throw new NotImplemented("bad luck");
    } 

    public override string FieldToString(object fieldValue) 
    { 
       var list = fieldValue as ICollection<UserFavourites>;

        return string.Join(",", 
            list.Select(f => f.ToString()));   // customize
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked great!!! I had to remove the {get;set;} from all of my properties so that the [FieldConvert] attribute worked properly, but other than that worked like a charm